# Retrieve array of objects from parent array of objects in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ionic3

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
Array1
(4) [{_index: "sitelist", _source:{dma: 1 , site :4}},{_index: "sitelist", _source:{dma: 2 , site :4}},{_index: "sitelist", _source:{dma: 3 , site :4}},{_index: "sitelist", _source:{dma: 4, site :4}}]
```

Now i wanted to retrieve the source object and store it in an array , desired output should be

```
Array2 
(4) [{dma: 1 , site :4},{dma: 2 , site :4},{dma: 3 , site :4},{dma: 4 , site :4}]
```

I have tried using the filter function as

```
let Array2 = Array1.filter(function(obj){
                return obj._source;
            });
```

When i **console.log(Array2)** i am not getting the desired result, i am getting Array1 values, How to get the proper output, any help appreciated.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: <kbd>[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)</kbd>

```
let result = Array1.map(x=>x._source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete:

```
let Array2 = Array1.filter(function(obj){
                 return delete(obj._index);
             })
```

Comment: If you what to use filter